# Weird padding issue across browsers with css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a navigation bar at the top of my page. It works fine in Chrome but when I test the page in Firefox it causes the navigation bar to gain a lot of extra padding.

This page is the page in question
http://acrmgmt.com/CW_testing/

I would really appreciate if someone could please tell me as to why there is an issue and how to fix it.

**Edit:** Fixed now but I have no idea what caused the problem or how it was fixed besides the fact that I turned my computer off and left for the day then came back the next morning and everything was fixed.

Comment: It looks the same to me. Please be more specific.

Comment: use https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to make sure browsers show the page the same way for different browsers

Comment: Could you please post the html and css here?

Comment: Looks the same for me too, are you zoomed in? lol

Comment: The pages look quite different when the browser window is smaller. Perhaps you're viewing the firefox version on a secondary monitor that is smaller? The elements on the page change size drastically when you resize the browser. Is this intended? Otherwise, Firefox looks the same here (latest). See: http://i.imgur.com/ntlOMUp.gif

Comment: to me when I view it on firefox the padding on the top nav bar is like 10 times bigger than what it should be

Comment: This looks the same with no issue in Firefox 38 and Chrome 43 on my machine (macbook pro)

Comment: on my srceen it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/PnLHiNn.png and I am using a 1600x900 monitor and it is only like that on firefox and I am using normalize.css

Comment: Be sure your cache is disabled. There are settings for most browsers that will automatically disable the cache when the inspector window is open.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any CSS reset methods at the start of your CSS?  This is a way to set most browsers to common default padding, margins etc, before your desired styles are applied.  Search on 'css reset'.

Comment: This should go in the comments, ask the question first.